# How to scrape the data when there's missing values in selector nodes

Tags: r, rvest

Hi I am trying scrape the data from ebay in R, I used the code mentioned below but I encountered with a problem wherein there were missing values for a particular selector elements, to get round it I used a for loop as shown(inspecting each listing and giving the number for which there was data missing) since the data scraped was less it was possible to inspect but how to do it when there's large amounts of data to be scraped.
Thanks in advance

```
library(rvest)

url<-"https://www.ebay.in/sch/i.html_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=4&_ipg=100&_nkw=samsung+j7"

web<- read_html(url)

subdescp<- html_nodes(web, ".lvsubtitle+ .lvsubtitle")

subdescp1<-html_text(subdescp)

head(subdescp1)

library(stringr)

subdescp1<- str_replace_all(subdescp1, "[\t\n\r]" , "")

head(subdescp1)

for (i in c(5,6,10,19,33,34,35)){
  a<-subdescp1[1:(i-1)]
  b<-subdescp1[i:length(subdescp1)]
  subdescp1<-append(a,list("NA"))
  subdescp1<-append(subdescp1,b)
}

Z<-as.character(subdescp1)
Z

webpage <- read_html(url)

Descp_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.vip')

Descp_data <- html_text(Descp_data_html)

head(Descp_data)

price_data_html <- html_nodes(web,'.prc .bold')

price_data <- html_text(price_data_html)

head(price_data)

library(stringr)

price_data<-str_replace_all(price_data, "[\t\n]" , "")

price_data<-gsub("Rs. ","",price_data)


price_data<-gsub(",","",price_data)

price_data<- as.numeric(price_data)

price_data

Desc_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.lvtitle+ .lvsubtitle')

Desc_data <- html_text(Desc_data_html, trim = TRUE)

head(Desc_data)

j7_f2<-data.frame(Title = Descp_data, Description= Desc_data, Sub_Description= Z, Pirce = price_data)
```

Comment: _"The use of robots or other automated means to access the eBay site without the express permission of eBay is strictly prohibited. Notwithstanding the foregoing, eBay may permit automated access to access certain eBay pages but solely for the limited purpose of including content in publicly available search engines."_

Comment: Just for educational purpose, don't worry

Comment: Pick a different site.

Answer (score 0):

For instance you can use something like this.

```
data <- read_html("url.xml")


var <- data %>% html_nodes("//node") %>% xml_text() 

# observations that don´t have certain nodes - fill them with NA
var_pair <- data %>% html_nodes("node_var_pair") 

var_missing_clean = sapply(var_pair, function(x) {
  tryCatch(xml_text(html_nodes(x, "./var_missing")),
           error=function(err) NA)
})

df = data.frame(var, var_pair, var_missing)
```

Here there are three types of nodes that you may consider. `var` gathers the nodes that do not have missing data. `var_pair` includes the nodes that you want to pair with the nodes that contain missing observation and `var_missing` refers to the nodes with missing information. You can create variables and aggregate them in a data data frame (`df`)

Comment: Are you sure the url is alright? It does not seem to work on the website

Comment: This is the one **https://www.ebay.in/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=4&_nkw=samsung%20j7&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&_trksid=p2045573.m1684**

Comment: For example: `data = read_html("https://www.ebay.in/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=4&_nkw=samsung%20j7&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&_trksid=p2045573.m1684")

name <-  data %>% html_nodes("h3") %>% 
  xml_text() %>% as.data.frame()` this would get you the names. Then you need to figure out which nodes contain the information that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The process here is simple and in two steps -- First extract all nodes at the block level (not each element and don't convert to text). This is a list of length equal to the number of blocks. Second from this extracted list extract each element as text and clean it. Since this is being done from a list, NA's where applicable are automatically coerced in the right places. See an example from the same ebay India site:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# specify the url
url <-"https://www.ebay.in/sch/Mobile-Phones"

# read the page
web <- read_html(url)

# define the supernode that has the entire block of information
super_node <- '.li' 

# read as vector of all blocks of supernode (imp: use html_nodes function)
super_node_read <- html_nodes(web, super_node)

# define each node element that you want
node_model_details <- '.lvtitle'
node_description_1 <- '.lvtitle+ .lvsubtitle'
node_description_2 <- '.lvsubtitle+ .lvsubtitle'
node_model_price   <- '.prc .bold'
node_shipping_info <- '.bfsp'

# extract the output for each as cleaned text (imp: use html_node function)
model_details <- html_node(super_node_read, node_model_details) %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_replace_all("[\t\n\r]" , "")

description_1 <- html_node(super_node_read, node_description_1) %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_replace_all("[\t\n\r]" , "")

description_2 <- html_node(super_node_read, node_description_2) %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_replace_all("[\t\n\r]" , "")

model_price  <- html_node(super_node_read, node_model_price) %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_replace_all("[\t\n\r]" , "")

shipping_info <- html_node(super_node_read, node_shipping_info) %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_replace_all("[\t\n\r]" , "")

# create the data.frame
mobile_phone_data <- data.frame(
    model_details,
    description_1,
    description_2,
    model_price,
    shipping_info
)
```